# Free server side anti virus / security / trojan protection for file uploads?

Tags: database, security, antivirus-integration

I am allowing users to upload photos like photo albums, and also attach files (documents for now) as mail attachments. So i assume I need some anti virus/security tool in place to scan the files first in case people upload infected stuff. So two questions:
1) Are there any 'free' or open source tools for this I can use or integrate into my environment: codeignitor php?
2) How to secure the upload area from rest of the system? Say the virus scanner fails to catch a virus and it is uploaded, how to prevent it from infecting other files? Like can the upload area be sandboxed in or something always and use that filepath for users to access the content so it does not spread to other parts of the system?

Answer (score 2):

There is clamav for a free virus scanner. Install it and you could do something like:

```
function virus_detected($filename)
{
        $clamscan = "/usr/local/bin/clamscan";
        $result = exec("$clamscan -i --no-summary $filename");
        return strlen($result)?true:false;
}
```

As for security, make sure the temporary files are uploaded to a directory outside of your web root. You should then verify the file type, rename the file to something other than it's original file name and append the appropriate extension (gif,jpg,bmp,png). I believe this should keep you fairly safe aside from exploits in php itself.

For more information about verifying file types in php check out:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

Comment: This won't work for exe files though because you can change their extensions.

Comment: I dont know if this works. It will kep it safe from php exploits but what about infecting the system? And how powerful is clamav like can it deliver enterprise level protection again all possible malware as an ultimate protection or do i still need more?

Comment: As far as anti virus applications go, none are perfect. Perhaps you could install multiple av apps and scan with each of them to have more peace of mind. I believe AVG, BitDefender, and Avast also have a linux version. If you're using a nix server, I believe that an infected file shouldn't impact your system itself unless executed. Perhaps someone with more knowledge on the subject would like to chime in.

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic hasn't been active for three years now, but, in case anyone else in the future, similarly, is looking for a PHP-based anti-virus solution, for those without an anti-virus daemon, program or utility installed on their host machine and without the ability to install an anti-virus daemon, program or utility, **[phpMussel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmussel/)**, a PHP script that I've written based on ClamAV that fits the bill for what Rohit (the the original poster) was looking for (a PHP-based anti-virus to protect their CMS against malicious file uploads),  may possibly be a viable solution. It certainly isn't perfect and I can't guarantee that it'll catch everything, but by far, it's certainly better than using nothing at all.

Ideally, as per already suggested above by Matt, making a call to shell to have ClamScan scan the file uploads is definitely an ideal solution, and if this is something that a hostmaster, webmaster or anyone in Rohit's situation is able to do, I'd second that suggestion wholly. What I've written, because it is a PHP script, has limitations inherent to anything that relies wholly on PHP in order to function, but, in instances where the aforementioned suggestion and/or similar suggestions aren't a possibility (such as if the host machine doesn't have an anti-virus installed and shell access is disabled; common with cheaper shared hosting solutions), that's where what I'm suggesting here could potentially step in - Something that only requires PHP to be installed (with PCRE extension included, which is standard with PHP nowadays anyhow), and nothing more.

Also remember, as Matt has already suggested, to always upload outside of your root directory, to ensure that uploaded files can't be exploited by attackers (such as in the event of an attacker attempting to compromise your system by uploading backdoors or trojans) - Viruses are not the only threat you need to worry about, and the vast majority of anti-virus solutions nowadays do not solely focus on viruses. Matt is also entirely correct in pointing out that no anti-virus solution is perfect, and for that reason, anyone allowing file uploads to their website or server needs to remain vigilant - An anti-virus solution is a must-have for anyone in that situation, but no holy grail of internet security that'll cover every possible threat exists. Also, renaming files isn't only about ensuring that they can't execute (as may be somewhat inferred by the original poster's reply comment regarding EXEs) - The risk of threats such as directory traversal attacks can be reduced by renaming files as well as the risk associated with an attacker attempting to override an already existing file on a targeted system as a means to hide their dirty-work.

Regarding the threat of files that may be malicious being missed by an anti-virus solution and then potentially infecting the system where they are being uploaded to; What a hostmaster or webmaster could potentially do in this situation is employ some sort of quick and simple encoding process that'd render the file non-executable by the system itself, but which can be easily and readily reversed by the PHP script responsible for calling that file on request, such as by way of using base64_encode(), bin2hex(), or even by just rotating a few characters and adding a salt to displace the file's magic number or something similar.