# State-of-the-art protection against anti-virus in web applications

Tags: file, http, security, web, malware

I plan to add anti-virus protection to our web application that is being built. I have a concern that even the limited amount of files (PDF files, images, or even unknown binaries) that the user uploads may contain viruses.

Concerns:

- The images are shared with other users (exposed to web pages) may contain viruses.
- The PDF files that users share with each other may contain viruses.

The API that I build for this web application handles the file upload and this API is the file server as well.

**Are there any state-of-the-art approaches to minimize the exposure of users to malware, including techniques in the API or techniques on the client-side (browser)? More specifically, I'm interested in solutions that would scan files in the API itself (backend).** The files may be stored in a database or on the file-system.

*I definitely searched Github for open-source tools and packages, moreover, ran several searches on Google against terms like "open source anti-virus API", "open-source malware HTTP API", but could not find any. Broader search terms resulted in a huge amount of unrelated results.*

**A [related and outdated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948576/free-server-side-anti-virus-security-trojan-protection-for-file-uploads) investigates a similar problem, but I'm looking for a solution that would integrate well into a micro-service architecture, like Kubernetes, moreover, I think a canonical answer would be useful from an expert.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are definitely solutions that can help you and integrate into your web application via an API. Here are a few that I am aware of:

1. SophosLabs Intelix

[Intelix](https://sophos.com/intelix) is a threat intelligence platform that provides access via APIs through AWS Marketplace. There are three parts to the service lookups, static analysis and dynamic analysis. Each one will give a more detailed analysis of the file. Combining the three will give you a good protection for your web application.

2. VirusTotal

[VirusTotal](http://virustotal.com/) is a community that will provide you with aggregated information showing you what various anti-malware vendors will say about your file. While VT is a great service, one thing to watch here is that VT is focused on being a community and therefore files uploaded are shared with others.

3. Clam AV

Not one that I have personal experience of but Clam AV allow you to spin up a server and then query it using API. There is a tutorial / documentation [here](https://blog.theodo.com/2017/11/implement-antivirus-api-10-min/).

4. Others

If you tweak your google search and look for Sandboxes most offer an API for a fee. A couple that come to mind [Joe Sandbox](https://joesecurity.org), [Falcon Sandbox](https://www.crowdstrike.com/endpoint-security-products/falcon-sandbox-malware-analysis/) which powers Hybrid Analysis.

As always, be careful of any cloud service that offers you scanning for free. Most of the free tools will share the reports and/or files within their community.